# Good client inventory/LAN tool

Tags: networking, inventory

I have been assigned the task of performing inventory of a few small Windows networks that is connected in a workgroup, and what would be very handy is the following:

1. Small client inventory program that will collect lots of information about the client, preferably a portable version that you can plug in to the clients with USB-stick. This information should be saved for later analysis.
2. Small network inventory (preferably portable) program that will attempt to scan the net for devices etc to create a network map, and the findings should also be saved.

Answer (score 1):

For part 1) my favorite free, portable tool is Free PC Audit by [MIS Utilities](http://www.misutilities.com/): "Free PC Audit is a freeware system, hardware and software information tool. It extracts details of all components of the PC, shows installed software with version and product key."

If you like that tool, they also offer Network Asset Tracker for $59 that likely will cover all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[10-Strike Software](http://www.10-strike.com) provides utilities for both tasks.

1. 10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer's client app can be started from a USB stick and collect the inventory data locally from a PC, and then save it to the stick. Later, you can import the data into the main program and primary PC database.

After the program installation, you can find the client app here
"C:\Program Files (x86)\10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer\Client"
Copy the Client folder to your USB stick and run the NIEClient.exe program on the desired PC. You can configure the client application using the nieclientcfg.exe configuration program (for example, select necessary inventory items, place the client shortcut to the startup folder, configure the polling schedule and pushing the data to an FTP or email server).

[image]

In the main program, you can import the data files manually
[image]

or configure their regular downloading from FTP or email if you want to configure the automatic monitoring of those remote computers over the Internet and track changes.

2. One simple scanning program is free. It's 10-Strike Network Scanner. It does not draw any maps but can find all connected devices and detect their addresses.

The second program 10-Strike Network Diagram is more advanced. It supports SNMP and LLDP, can discover the network topology, and create a network map displaying the connection links and port names on managed switches.

Comment: The 10-Strike Network Diagram seems to be very handy in its creation of network maps, but the only drawback I could see was that it was only possible to save the graphic network map, but not the actual raw detected device data, but perhaps I just need to get more familiar with the program.

Comment: You can save a report in the end of the Scanning Wizard operation.